# Connecting to git remote from Laravel devcontainer on VSC on windows

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, ssh, git-remote, devcontainer

I'm using a devcontainer in Visaul Studio Code on Windows.
I built this devcontainer with the laravel sail helper. It runs on Docker desktop and WSL2.

This is the devcontainer json:

```
// https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "Existing Docker Compose (Extend)",
    "dockerComposeFile": [
        "../docker-compose.yml"
    ],
    "service": "laravel.test",
    "workspaceFolder": "/var/www/html",
    "settings": {},
    "extensions": [
        // "mikestead.dotenv",
        // "amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense",
        // "ryannaddy.laravel-artisan",
        // "onecentlin.laravel5-snippets",
        // "onecentlin.laravel-blade"
    ],
    "remoteUser": "sail",
    // "forwardPorts": [],
    // "runServices": [],
    // "postCreateCommand": "apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl",
    // "shutdownAction": "none",
}
```

And this is the docker composer file:

```
# For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/sail
version: '3'
services:
    laravel.test:
        build:
            context: ./docker/8.1
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
            args:
                WWWGROUP: '${WWWGROUP}'
                XDEBUG: ${SAIL_DEBUG}
        image: sail-8.1/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'
        volumes:
            - '.:/var/www/html'
        networks:
            - sail
        depends_on:
            - mariadb
    mariadb:
        image: 'mariadb:10'
        ports:
            - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
            MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
            MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'no'
        volumes:
            - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
            - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
        networks:
            - sail
        healthcheck:
            test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-p${DB_PASSWORD}"]
            retries: 3
            timeout: 5s
networks:
    sail:
        driver: bridge
volumes:
    sail-mariadb:
        driver: local
```

It's been working really well for working locally and pushing to my github repo.

But now I need to make a push to the production site.

So I tried

```
git remote add namecheap xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx/home/user
git push namecheap dev


Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port xxxx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So I tried a few things which didn't work. Could someone kindly explain HOW I could add a ssh key to this devcontainer or forward the agent?
Bear in mind that all the basic linux tools are missing. I don't even have vim or sudo inside this container. And have no idea how to add them. And do not know the SU password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on this approach and instead called a git pull from the production site, after figuring out how to access the terminal